# What exactly does args do in scipy optimize?

Tags: python, finance, portfolio, scipy-optimize

I have been following a class that teaches portfolio optimisation, and in the markowitz optimiser I noticed that in one of the constraints

```
def minimize_vol(target_return, er, cov):
    """
    target_ret ---> W (weight vector)
    """
    n = er.shape[0]
    init_guess = np.repeat(1/n, n)

    bounds = ((0.0, 1.0),) * n

    return_is_target = {
        "type":"eq",
        "args": (er,),
        "fun": lambda weights, er: target_return - portfolio_return(weights, er)
    }
    weights_sum_to_1 =  {
        "type": "eq",
        "fun": lambda weights: np.sum(weights) - 1
    }
    results = minimize(portfolio_vol, init_guess, args=(cov,), method="SLSQP", options={"disp":False}, constraints=(return_is_target, weights_sum_to_1), bounds=bounds)
    
    return results.x
```

What does the "args" in the first constraint dictionary do exactly? I couldn't get a clear idea on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the parameters/weights, you can pass additional arguments to the objective function, as well as to the functions that define the constraints.

In

```
    return_is_target = {
      "type":"eq",
      "args": (er,),
      "fun": lambda weights, er: target_return - portfolio_return(weights, er)
    }
```

the function defining the constraint is `lambda weights, er: target_return - portfolio_return(weights, er)`. It requires an additional argument, i.e. `er`. Using the `args` key you can pass this additional argument to that function.

However, in this particular case, you could have fixed `er` in the function definition as follows:

```
    return_is_target = {
      "type":"eq",
      "fun": lambda weights: target_return - portfolio_return(weights, er)
    }
```

Now `er` is no longer an argument of your constraint and thus need not be passed via `args`.